# Scrape links from wikidata page

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

```
<table class="sparql" border="1">
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>simpleProperty</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P115c">http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P115c</a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Using Jsoup, I'm trying to collect all the links from pages that look like [this](http://milenio.dcc.uchile.cl/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX+%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT+*+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A+++%3AQ855+%3FsimpleProperty+%3AQ233999%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on).

I've been trying many different ways, but I can't seem to pin it down. Most recently I tried like this:

```
// parse the input stream using Jsoup
docx = Jsoup.parse(wiki_relation_InputStream, null, wikidata_relation_page.getProtocol()+"://"+wikidata_relation_page.getHost()+"/");

Element table = doc.select("table").first(); //gets a table with the class "first class"
Elements links = table.select("a[href]");
```

It seems it should be easy because the structure is so minimal, but alas, nevertheless it's causing me a bit of trouble.

In the case that there is more than one I'd like to collect them all. In the case that there are zero I'd prefer if the program didn't crash in a fireball of death and destruction.

How to get that elusive link text? (as in `http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P115c` for instance)

### Update

on the suggestion of panda

```
//get it's normal wiki disambig page
String URL_czech = "http://milenio.dcc.uchile.cl/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX+%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT+*+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A+++%3A" 
        + home + "+%3FsimpleProperty+%3A" 
        + away + "%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on";

URL wikidata_page = new URL(URL_czech);
HttpURLConnection wiki_connection = (HttpURLConnection)wikidata_page.openConnection();
InputStream wikiInputStream = null;


try 
{
    // try to connect and use the input stream
    wiki_connection.connect();
    wikiInputStream = wiki_connection.getInputStream();
} 
catch(IOException error) 
{
    // failed, try using the error stream
    wikiInputStream = wiki_connection.getErrorStream();
}
    // parse the input stream using Jsoup
    Document docx = Jsoup.parse(wikiInputStream, null, wikidata_page.getProtocol()+"://"+wikidata_page.getHost()+"/");



Elements link_text = docx.select("table.sparql > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > a");
//link_text.text();
for (Element l : link_text) 
{
    String output = l.text();
    System.out.println( output );
}
```

The following thing can get the table but how to drill down farther:

```
Elements tables = docx.select("table.sparql");

for(Element table : tables)
{
     System.out.println(table.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following CSS Selector query on http://try.jsoup.org/ and it seems to be getting me the text `http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P26c`:

```
table.sparql > tbody > tr:nth-child(2)
```

Try this code:

```
Element link_text = document.select("table.sparql > tbody > tr:nth-child(2)");
link_text.getText(); //or I think its text() method
```

This also seems to work fine:

`table.sparql > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > a`

Comment: that seems great, but i'm not getting anything :/

Comment: What are you getting when you print the `text` property after trying this query?

Comment: i was getting nothing but i just tried. `                      if(docx.select("table.sparql.tbody.r:nth-child(2)") != null)
                      {
                       System.out.println("yes");
                      }` and it output `yes` twice

Comment: No, I mean you have to try and use the `text()` function after getting the element. If not, then try the other one I've posted.

Comment: i posted what ive just been doing to the place, **update** in the op but it's still just outputting nothing, even I've tried both of your CSS statements.

Comment: Actually Ive tried all queries posted in this answer as well as the other answer. Why dont you goto http://try.jsoup.org/, and try out your query online. See whats going wrong.

Comment: maybe its something with how I'm connecting, i posted also the code I used to get the page, can you see anything wrong with it? I don't see how that could be possible becasue i used exactly that code before

Comment: Can you try printing your docx object? Also, share the url if you can.

Comment: sorry for being such an obstenent moron, i just checked and on a clean slate your code works great, i was having other troubles, related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919848/large-database-operation-check-for-relatedness-between-entities)

Answer (score 1):

Would this do the job?

```
List<String> links = new ArrayList<>();
for(Element a : doc.select("table.sparql tr td a")) {
   String href = a.attr("href");
   String linkText = a.text();
   links.add(href);
}
```

Comment: no, but it should be correct in principal based on your example html. It is only a snippet that you will have to expand for your purpose. Also, your updated code cannot work as "tbody.tr.td" means `<tbody class="tr td"`

Comment: how to do it, like i mean?

Comment: like, i think you know what i'm tyring to get, the table data, inside of the table row, you know

Comment: I have already answered the jsoup part, the rest is just java 101:

    List<String> links = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Element a : doc.select("table.sparql tr td a")) {
        String href = a.attr("href");
        String linkText = a.text();
        links.add(href);
    }

Comment: sorry for being such a dickhead, i just checked and on a clean slate your code works great, i was having other troubles, related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919848/large-database-operation-check-for-relatedness-between-entities)